# Определение количества вхождений букв слова в предложение

Tags: c, строки

Слова не должны превышать 20 букв. Предложение не должно превышать 30 слов, разделенных одним или несколькими пробелами.Предложение должно оканчиваться символом "." или "!" или "?" 
Вот эти условия я выполнил в своем коде, нужна помощь с алгоритмом :
"по слову печатает количество вхождений каждой его буквы в предложение (повторно встречающиеся в слове буквы игнорировать)"
Я так понял, что нужно завести еще один массив символов для ключевого слова и туда забить неповторяющиеся символы , после чего по каждому символу проверить строку на количество вхождений, но вот идей , как это все реализовать - 0. Мой код ниже.

```
// по слову печатает количество вхождений каждой его буквы в предложении
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define W 31
#define S 21
#define N 21
int main()
{
    char str[W][S];
    char wrd[N], ch;
    int i,word = 0, symb = 0, count = 0;
    char c;
    setlocale(0, "");
    i = 0;
    printf("введите слово пжлст введите я прошу вас\n");
    while (1) // вводится слово,по которому определеяется количество вхождений букв.
    {
    ch = getchar();
    if (ch == '\n')
        break;
    if (i >= N)
        break;
    wrd[i++] = ch;
    }
        printf("Введите предложение: \n"); // ввод предложения, в котором ищутся вхождения.
    while (c = getchar())
    {
        if ( c == '\n')
        {
            symb = 0;
            word = 0;
            count = 0;
            printf("Не выполнены условия предложения, попробуйте снова: \n");

        }
        if (c == '.' || c == '!' || c == '?')
        {
            str[word][symb] = '\0';
            count++;
            break;
        }
        if (c != ' ')
        {
            str[word][symb] = c;
            symb++;
        }
        else
        {
            str[word][symb] = '\0';
            symb = 0;
            word++;
            count++;
        }

        if (symb > S || word > W)
        {
            printf("Не выполнены условия предложения.");
            getch();
            return 0;
        }
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "забить" +1 *(2 символа нужно...)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> нужно завести еще один массив символов

Да, нужен массив отдельных символов (а строка и есть массив отдельных символов). Но нужен ещё целый массив со счётчиками вхождений соответствующих символов.

> туда забить неповторяющиеся символы

- Отсортируйте символы в исходном слове по порядку значений кодов символов.
- Скопируйте их в итоговый массив, НЕ копируая те символы, котрые совпадают с последним скопированным

Если лень самому писать функцию сортировки, то можете воспользоваться стандартной *qsort*.

> по каждому символу проверить строку на количество вхождений

Проверка вхождения символа в строку выполняется функцией *strchr()*. Легко подсчитать количество таких вхождений, вызывая эту функцию в цикле, пока она не вернёт NULL. Как-то так:

```
int n = 0; //Найдено вхождений
char c = 'w'; // Искомый символ
char *cp = sentence; // Адрес начала предложения

while ((cp = strchr(cp, c) != NULL) {
    n++; // Найдено вхождение символа
    cp = cp+1; // Переходим на символ, следующий за найденным
}
```

while